# VL53L3CX XSHUT PIN PROBLEM IN DEEP SLEEP

Tags: esp32, proximity-sensor, power-consumption, distance, sleep

I have project using a VL53L3CX distance sensor. Also , I control it by ESP32. In normally, I can command to XSHUT pin. And I can read xshut pin of ESP32 that is **3V3 or 0V.**

But, When ESP32 enters deep-sleep mode for current consumption, XSHUT pin of the ESP32 is **2V8.**
So, My power consumption is too high. Because I can not turn of the VL53L3CX sensor.

In addition, is it ok if i drive XHUT pin directly through ESP32 IO? (No pull up,no ESD protection resistor)

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

[image: dsitance sensor]

[image: levelshifter]